# Using gem (socialization) method through AJAX in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rubygems

I am using the [Socialization gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) and I have what I think is actually a basic rails question. I want to use the `follow` or `like` gem methods through AJAX. How do you use a gem method like that in ajax? Will I need to create a controller (the gem does not automatically generate them) or is there a simpler way?